# I want to use few variables that are extracted using JSON extractor in other controller in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

In Jmeter,From an api I have extracted two variables which has many values using a json extractor the extracted variable are something like this

First variable is name which has data like {abc,asd,qwe,dff,hjk,lku,ghs,jjss}
So used the json extractor with variable name as name and have given path expression as $..name and match number as -1 and checked the suffix ALL

And second variable is id which has data like {123,344,6383,0298383,8282}
Again used json extractor with variable name as id path expression is $..id with match number-1 and checked the suffix ALL

These two variables are from a get api that is placed inside a for each controller1.

Now there is a other for each controller2 which has other get api same in this I have used json extractor and extracted two variables naming idd and namee
And I have written a compare code in this controller using bean shell assertion.(used the general compare code)

When the script is run I get a assertion error. Like the expected data field is empty, this expected data has to have the foreach controller1 variable data... Actual data i.e., foreach controller2 data is shown correctly.

If I don't place these 2 api's in  for each controller the assertion works fine, but I need to use a controller as looping is needed

How to use one controller variables in other controller?

I have tried using

${__setProperty(name,${name})} in bean shell for first for each controller

Then used ${__property(name)} in the controller 2 beanshell assertion in the compare code to compare

This didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you have [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
id_1=123
id_2=344
id_3=6383
etc.
```

from the first sampler

and variables like:

```
idd_1=123
idd_2=344
idd_3=6383
```

from the second sampler

and want to compare them one by one using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) it needs to be configured as follows:

[image]

Then in [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/) you will be able to refer current value of `idd` variable as `vars.get('idd')` and current value of the relevant `id` variable as `vars.get('id_' + ((vars.get('__jm__ForEach Controller__idx') as int) + 1))`

Example code:

```
def expected = vars.get('idd')
def actual = vars.get('id_' + ((vars.get('__jm__ForEach Controller__idx') as int) + 1))

log.info('idd variable value: ' + expected)
log.info('id  variable value: ' + actual)

if (expected != actual) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Expected: ' + expected + ', actual: ' + actual) 
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Actually the idd is taken from the get api response so can I give id_ALL and idd_ALL in jsr223 assertion